# Mineable Tokens? Is it possible? If so, how can I make one?

Tags: go-ethereum, tokens, wallets, mist, ethereum-wallet-dapp

Just wondering if you could make a ethereum token that is mineable. I saw this link, but don't really know about it and i dont know anything about solidity. Can someone please help me? Thanks, Crypthusiast

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you could build this quite easily with [OpenZeppelin](https://openzeppelin.org/) along with EIP 918

Take a look at [EIP 918: Mineable Token Standard](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-918). Proposed interface:

```
contract ERC918  {

   function mint(uint256 nonce) public returns (bool success);

   function getAdjustmentInterval() public view returns (uint);

   function getChallengeNumber() public view returns (bytes32);

   function getMiningDifficulty() public view returns (uint);

   function getMiningTarget() public view returns (uint);

   function getMiningReward() public view returns (uint);

   function hash(uint256 _nonce, address _minter) public returns (bytes32 digest);

   function _reward(address _minter) internal returns (uint);

   function _epoch() internal returns (uint);

   function _adjustDifficulty() internal returns (uint);

   event Mint(address indexed from, uint rewardAmount, uint epochCount, bytes32 newChallengeNumber);
}
```

Comment: Can you make it so i can copy and paste into it, i am a noob and dont know how

Comment: The funniest request I have seen :)